# WPF: Invisible Control (?)

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I try to understand, why the WPF Control, or derived from control custom controls aren't visible ever:

Say, we have the following:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication13.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication13"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <DockPanel Name="dockPanel1" Background="LightBlue">

        <Canvas DockPanel.Dock="Left" ToolTip="tt one" Width="200" Background="Blue">
            <Control Background="Red" ToolTip="tt control" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="5" Width="50" Height="100"></Control>
        </Canvas>

        <Button Content="two" DockPanel.Dock="Left" ToolTip="tt two" ></Button>
        <!--<my:MyControl Background="Red" ToolTip="tt hello" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="5"></my:MyControl>-->

        <Control Background="Red" ToolTip="tt hello" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="5"></Control>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Any presence of the indicated Controls - any border, any tooltip, any background is not detected.

Why this, and how to make the controls visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that delaring a control like that in XAML does not mean anything since is does not represent something visual on itself.

You need to define a template for that control and for the controls inside, bind their property with TemplateBinding.

something like that :

```
        <Canvas DockPanel.Dock="Left" ToolTip="tt one" Width="200" Background="Blue">
        <Control Background="Red" ToolTip="tt control" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="5" Width="50" Height="100">
            <Control.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="Hello" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Control.Template>
        </Control>
    </Canvas>
```

Answer (score 4):

The `Control` class is the base class for controls that can be templated, but it doesn't define a template itself. And a control with no template has no visual tree, so it doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

Found some explanation from [MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.aspx)

A `Control` that does not have a `ControlTemplate` is not visible in your application, and setting the following properties has no effect unless the `ControlTemplate` references them explicitly:

- Background
- BorderBrush
- BorderThickness
- FontFamily
- FontSize
- FontStretch
- FontWeight
- Foreground
- HorizontalContentAlignment
- VerticalContentAlignment

A common way to use these properties is to bind an element in the ControlTemplate to the property. For example, if you want your control to change color according to the value of the Background property, you can bind some property of an element in the ControlTemplate to the Background. Use the TemplateBinding Markup Extension to bind properties on a control to an element in the ControlTemplate.

Comment: Yep :) MSDN is saying it way better than me ;) Don't forget to mark your answer as resolved if you think your question was answered